# How can I find lines with grep count=[some number >0] if my file contains count=0 as well as count=!0?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I want to grep all lines which contain `count=<some number>` except those that have `count=0`.

For example, if my file has these lines

```
Line1:  Hi it is text   count=0   yes
Line2:    Good count=2 bye bye 
Line3:   hi how are you count=3
Line4: -68 nice count=987 bye
```

I want my command to return lines 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Please clarify what you want to count.

Comment: I suggest `grep -E 'count=([1-9]+|[0-9][0-9]+)'`

Comment: It is not working

Comment: I suggest you give a real sample of your actual input and the output you want from that sample, as for all text processing questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood question, the answer is:
You can grep for "count=0" and invert match with the following command:
`grep --invert-match ^count=0$`

To grep file, add it as option:
`grep --invert-match ^count=0$ filename`

Above grep command expect only "count=X" in every line of file, without additional characters in line. If file contains something more then "count=X" then correct grep command is `grep --invert-match count=0 filename`. Symbols ^ and $ match beginning and end of line.

If your file contains some lines without `count=some_num` at all and you don't want this lines in output, then grep looks like this: `grep -E 'count=([1-9]+|[0-9][0-9]+)'`  - this will grep for count=num where num above zero. It fails only if you have 'count=00' line - with two or more zero
(^ Contributed by [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna))

Testing:

```
leonid@DevSSD:~$ cat txt
count=0aaaa
bbb count=1 aaaa
bbb count=999 aaaa
line without pattern
leonid@DevSSD:~$ grep --invert-match count=0 txt
bbb count=1 aaaa
bbb count=999 aaaa
line without pattern
leonid@DevSSD:~$ grep -E 'count=([1-9]+|[0-9][0-9]+)' txt
bbb count=1 aaaa
bbb count=999 aaaa
```

Comment: If my answer is not what you looking for, edit a question, and include example of file to grep

Comment: It not working,  its give error

Comment: I can't guess it. What error?

Comment: Please update question/or comment with exact command you try to run, and example of the file to grep. My grep command should not give error, may be you using it wrongly somehow.

Comment: I think OP wants to find lines that have `count=<some number>` rather than just avoid lines that have `count=0`. Inverting the match will return all lines that don't contain that text whether they have `count=<some number>` or not. I think a utility that can count would be better than `grep` for that...

Comment: @Zanna We can only guess that OP wants. He even didn't provide example of file, it appear after one of edits by other people. I can count/grep in any possible way, when OP provide more information, but all what he writes "it give error"

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using sed.

```
grep "count=" | sed -e '/"count=0"/d'
```

Comment: What about `count=08`, for example? I’d add `$` to your pattern, just like [LeonidMew did](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129854/250300).

Comment: This is also not working